# setOnClickListener on imageview needs to be clicked twice to work

Tags: android, xml, onclick

I've made ImageViews with setonclicklistener, but the image needs to be clicked twice to work. I can't understand why is this happening. Welp!

my xml for ImageView, it's in relativelayout:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bNext"
            android:layout_width="64.785dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/next" >
        </ImageView>
```

my code for the ImageView:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {        
    ...........    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
            ......
        final ImageView next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bNext);    
        ...............
        next.setOnClickListener(this);    
    }    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        ...................
        case R.id.bNext:
            if (j != imageCount) {
                image = imageArray[j];
                rl.setBackgroundResource(image);
                j = j + 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

EDIT: As asked, the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    int i, j = 0;
    final int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.w1, R.drawable.w2, R.drawable.w3 };
    int image;
    final int imageCount = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        final int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.w1, R.drawable.w2, R.drawable.w3 };
        image = imageArray[0];

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlBackground);

        final ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        final ImageView save = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        final ImageView next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bNext);

        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bBack:
            if (j != 0) {
                image = imageArray[j - 1];
                rl.setBackgroundResource(image);
                j = j - 1;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bSave:
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = 2;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image,
                    opts);
            SaveImage savefile = new SaveImage();
            savefile.SaveImagee(this, bm);
            break;
        case R.id.bNext:
            if (j != imageCount) {
                image = imageArray[j];
                rl.setBackgroundResource(image);
                j = j + 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the j variable come from? you should post more complete code

Comment: I leaved out the unimportant code, everything works fine. When I run the app, I need to click Next button twice to trigger the buttons function, I need it to work when I click it once, but I can't figure out why it wants to be clicked twice. I leaved only the code that's related to onClick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with focus. You have to press once for the `View` to gain focus then again to trigger the `onClick()`. Change your `ImageView` to an `ImageButton` and you shouldn't have this problem since `Buttons` are designed to have focus.

Just change

```
android:src="@drawable/next"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/next"
```

You also could implement an `onTouchListener` and set that on the `ImageView` then listen to the key actions to determine what to do but I'm not sure this is worth it.

[Here I found an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832888/android-on-focus-listener-and-on-click-listener-on-imageview) that may help.

Comment: It needs to be clicked twice too. The same goes for Button too. I'll try to do that onTouchListener thing.